# How to initialize Cloudinary through Secrets.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloudinary

I'm using [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) to host and manage images of my rails 4+ app. Its `api_secret`, `api_keys` and other config is put into the production environment using a `cloudinary.yml` file inside the `config` folder.

Instead of a separate `cloudinary.yml` file I wish to use the `secrets.yml` file utility provided in rails 4+ to port the environment variables (various secret and keys) into the production environment. Intent is to keep it all at one place of my project and simply use a regular Capistrano recipe to deploy.

I wonder if there's a way to write on `secrets.yml` like so:

```
production:
  CL_CLOUD_NAME: MyAppName
  CL_API_KEY: 'the_key'
  CL_API_SECRET: the_secret
  CL_ENHANCE_IMAGE_TAG: true/false
  CL_STATIC_IMAGE_SUPPORT: true/false
  CL_STATIC_SECURE: true/false
```

and be called in with `$ cap production deploy`?

---

[Edits] Old question:

I wonder if there is a way to use an initializer inside `ROOT/config/initializers/cloudinary.rb` where I can put lines something like this:

```
Cloudinary.configure do |c|
  c.cloud_name = Rails.application.secrets.CL_CLOUD_NAME
  c.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.CL_API_KEY
  c.api_secret = Rails.application.secrets.CL_API_SECRET
  c.secure = Rails.application.secrets.CL_STATIC_SECURE
end
```

Comment: For anyone still looking, the documentation on how to do this is [here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_additional_topics#configuration_options).

Comment: Not via secrets.yml though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Cloudinary.config do |c|
 c.cloud_name = XXX
end
```